# Make a frequent RSpec edit easy & repeatable

Tags: key-bindings, macro, repeated-commands

Writing unit tests in RSpec, I frequently change something like this,

```
it 'eats pizza' do
  pizza = build(:pizza)
  expect(subject.eats?(pizza)).to be_true
end
```

to this,

```
let(:pizza) { build(:pizza) }

it 'eats pizza' do
  expect(subject.eats?(pizza)).to be_true
end
```

I want to automate part of this to easily (and repeatably) convert

```
name = value
```

to

```
let(:name) { value }
```

I've done it with a macro:

```
mzIlet(:<Esc>ea)<Esc>f=r{A }<Esc>`z
```

but I'd like something I can put in my vimrc. I came up with a command as well:

```
command! -bang Let execute "normal! mzIlet\<bang>(:\<Esc>ea)\<Esc>f=r{A }\<Esc>`z"
```

which is a little better, since I can run `:Let` to get `let(:name)` or `:Let!` to get `let!(:name)`. But it's not repeatable with the dot command (though `@:` is a decent consolation in this case).

Going one step further, this searches backwards for the first `let`, `context`, or `describe` line and puts the `let` line below it:

```
command! -bang Let execute "normal! dd?\\v^%(\\s+let>)|%(\\s*%(context|describe)>)\<CR>p==Ilet\<bang>(:\<Esc>ea)\<Esc>f=r{A }\<Esc>`'"
```

Really feels like something that's outgrowing a command, and should be implemented as a function.

How can I make this repeatable? Is a command not the way to go with this? Looks like tpope's repeat.vim can make key-maps repeatable.

*Update*
The implementation has changed, as the problem is a better fit for pattern matching & substitution than I originally realized. I haven't made it `.` repeatable yet, but that's the next step (and thanks to @saginaw for the advice below).

```
func! RSpecLet(bang)
  delete
  normal! mz

  call MoveAssignment()
  call ReplaceWithLet(a:bang)

  normal! `z
endf

func! MoveAssignment()
  call search('\v^\s*<let>|<context>|<describe>', 'b')
  put
  normal! ==
endf

func! ReplaceWithLet(bang)
  execute 'substitute/\v^\s+\zs'
        \ '(\w+)%(\s*\=\s*)(.*\S)\s*$/'
        \ 'let'.a:bang.'(:\1) { \2 }'
endf
command! -bang Let call RSpecLet('<bang>')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your first command repeatable with dot, you could try the following code:

```
function! s:RSpecLet(bang)
    if a:bang ==# '!'
        execute "normal! mzIlet!(:\eea)\ef=r{A }\e`z"
        call repeat#set("\<Plug>RSpecBangLet")
    else
        execute "normal! mzIlet(:\eea)\ef=r{A }\e`z"
        call repeat#set("\<Plug>RSpecLet")
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecLet     :<C-U>call <SID>RSpecLet('')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecBangLet :<C-U>call <SID>RSpecLet('!')<CR>

command! -bang Let call s:RSpecLet('<bang>')
```

Note that it calls the `repeat#set()` function provided by the [repeat plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) from tpope, so you would need to install the latter to make the previous code work.

If you don't want to install a plugin, it can be done, but the code would be around 40 lines longer.

If you want the code to be a bit easier to understand, you could break down your editions into small chunks (each of them could be preceded by a comment if needed) like this:

```
function! s:RSpecLet(bang)
    normal! mz

    if a:bang ==# '!'
        normal! Ilet!(:
    else
        normal! Ilet(:
    endif

    normal! ea)
    normal! f=r{A }
    normal! `z

    if a:bang ==# '!'
        call repeat#set("\<Plug>RSpecBangLet")
    else
        call repeat#set("\<Plug>RSpecLet")
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecLet     :<C-U>call <SID>RSpecLet('')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecBangLet :<C-U>call <SID>RSpecLet('!')<CR>

command! -bang Let call s:RSpecLet('<bang>')
```

---

To make the 2nd command repeatable with dot, you could try the following code, similar to the previous one:

```
function! s:RSpecLet(bang)
    if a:bang ==# '!'
        execute "normal! dd?\\v^%(\\s+let>)|%(\\s*%(context|describe)>)\rp==Ilet!(:\eea)\ef=r{A }\e`'"
        call repeat#set("\<Plug>RSpecBangLet")
    else
        execute "normal! dd?\\v^%(\\s+let>)|%(\\s*%(context|describe)>)\rp==Ilet(:\eea)\ef=r{A }\e`'"
        call repeat#set("\<Plug>RSpecLet")
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecLet     :<C-U>call <SID>RSpecLet('')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecBangLet :<C-U>call <SID>RSpecLet('!')<CR>

command! -bang Let call s:RSpecLet('<bang>')
```

---

I've read your edit and I think you're right, your new implementation is probably better.
If you want to make it repeatable, here's a possible solution:

```
func! RSpecLet(bang)
  delete
  normal! mz

  call MoveAssignment()
  call ReplaceWithLet(a:bang)

  execute 'call repeat#set("\<Plug>RSpec' . a:bang . 'Let")'
  normal! `z
endf

func! MoveAssignment()
  call search('\v^\s*<let>|<context>|<describe>', 'b')
  put
  normal! ==
endf

func! ReplaceWithLet(bang)
  execute 'substitute/\v^\s+\zs'
        \ '(\w+)%(\s*\=\s*)(.*\S)\s*$/'
        \ 'let'.a:bang.'(:\1) { \2 }'
endf

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecLet  :<C-U>call RSpecLet('')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpec!Let :<C-U>call RSpecLet('!')<CR>

command! -bang Let call RSpecLet('<bang>')
```

If you don't want to install the repeat.vim plugin, here's another possible solution (which copies the bare minimum from the original plugin):

```
func! RSpecLet(bang)
  delete
  normal! mz

  call MoveAssignment()
  call ReplaceWithLet(a:bang)

  execute 'call RepeatSet("\<Plug>RSpec' . a:bang . 'Let")'
  normal! `z
endf

func! MoveAssignment()
  call search('\v^\s*<let>|<context>|<describe>', 'b')
  put
  normal! ==
endf

func! ReplaceWithLet(bang)
  execute 'substitute/\v^\s+\zs'
        \ '(\w+)%(\s*\=\s*)(.*\S)\s*$/'
        \ 'let'.a:bang.'(:\1) { \2 }'
endf

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpecLet  :<C-U>call RSpecLet('')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>RSpec!Let :<C-U>call RSpecLet('!')<CR>

command! -bang Let call RSpecLet('<bang>')

func! RepeatSet(sequence,...)
    let g:repeat_sequence = a:sequence
    let g:repeat_count = a:0 ? a:1 : v:count
    let g:repeat_tick = b:changedtick
endf

func! RepeatDot(count)
    if g:repeat_tick == b:changedtick
      let c = g:repeat_count
      let cnt = (a:count ? a:count : (c ? c : ''))
      call feedkeys(g:repeat_sequence, 'i')
      call feedkeys(cnt, 'ni')
    else
      call feedkeys((a:count ? a:count : '') . '.', 'ni')
    endif
endf

func! RepeatWrap(command)
  let sync_test = (g:repeat_tick == b:changedtick)
  execute 'normal! ' . a:command . 'zv'
  if sync_test
    let g:repeat_tick = b:changedtick
  endif
endf

let g:repeat_tick = -1
augroup Repeat
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufLeave,BufWritePre,BufReadPre * let g:repeat_tick =
          \ (g:repeat_tick == b:changedtick || g:repeat_tick == 0) ? 0 : -1

  autocmd BufEnter,BufWritePost * if g:repeat_tick == 0 |
          \ let g:repeat_tick = b:changedtick |
          \ endif
augroup END

nmap .     <Plug>(RepeatDot)
nmap u     <Plug>(RepeatUndo)
nmap U     <Plug>(RepeatUndoLine)
nmap <C-R> <Plug>(RepeatRedo)

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(RepeatDot)      :<C-U>call RepeatDot(v:count)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(RepeatUndo)     :<C-U>call RepeatWrap('u')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(RepeatUndoLine) :<C-U>call RepeatWrap('U')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(RepeatRedo)     :<C-U>call RepeatWrap("\<Lt>C-R>")<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternate solution using a plugin I created. The plugin is called [express.vim](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-express), and it helps with the creation of ad-hoc operators. With it, you can create two types of operators:

- Operators that run a VimScript expression over the supplied motion
- Operators that perform a substitution over the supplied motion

One thing I observed is that your edit could be performed using the `:substitute` command:

```
:s/\(.\{-}\)\s*=\s*\(.*\)/let(:\1) { \2 }/
```

The pattern looks for text like `foo = bar`, capturing the left and right hand sides of the `=` sign; the replacement inserts them into the RSpec `let` statement as you specified.

To create an operator that does this over a motion, we can use the `:MapSubpress` command. In the below example, we'll map it to `cd`.

```
:MapSubpress cd /\(.\{-}\)\s*=\s*\(.*\)/let(:\1) { \2 }/
```

Now `cd` is an operator that we can use and repeat with `.` (this also depends on [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat)). Note that since it's an *operator*, it requires a motion to follow (just as `c` or `y` would). Since you're usually operating on lines, the `_` motion will suffice. So we could use `cd_` to transform `foo = bar` into `let(:foo) { bar }`.

If you're *always* operating on a line, you might as well make a mapping that always invokes the `_` motion. For this, I'd use a `<Plug>` mapping with `:MapSubpress`, and then create a map that refers to it. You could put something like this in your `vimrc`:

```
MapSubpress <Plug>(rspec-let) /\(.\{-}\)\s*=\s*\(.*\)/let(:\1) { \2 }/
nmap cd <Plug>(rspec-let)_
```

Now, our `cd` mapping will operate on whole lines every time, and it's still repeatable with `.`.